# DB Design - any way to avoid duplicating columns here?

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a database that stores hash values and a few pieces of data about the hash, all in one table. One of the fields is 'job_id', which is the ID for the job that the hash came from.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that with this design, a hash can only belong to one job - in reality a hash can occur in many jobs, and I'd like to know each job in which a hash occurs.

The way I'm thinking of doing this is to create a new table called 'Jobs', with fields 'job_id', 'job_name' and 'hash_value'. When a new batch of data is inserted into the DB, the job ID and name would be created here and each hash would go into here as well as the original hash table, but in the Jobs table it'd also be stored against the job.

I don't like this, because I'd be duplicating the hash column across tables. Is there a better way? I can add to the hash table but can't take away any columns because closed-source software depends on it. The hash value is the primary key. It's MySQL and the database stores many millions of records. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's called **one-to-many relationship** (1:N). Just store hash in a separate table and then use its primary key with each `job_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the new `job` table is the way to go. It's the normative practice, for representing a one-to-many relationship.

It's good to avoid unnecessary duplication of values. But in this case, you aren't really "duplicating" the `hash_value` column; rather, you are really defining a relationship between `job` and the table that has `hash_value` as the primary key.

The relationship is implemented by adding a column to the child table; that column holds the primary key value from the parent table. Typically, we add a FOREIGN KEY constraint on the column as well.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I think I'd feel happier about it if the hash table had a 'proper' primary key like an incrementing int. I don't do much database work these days but I still have that instinctive feel for when something just feels wrong. It's going to seriously add to the size of the data as well - there's upwards of 60 million hashes in there.

Comment: @BenUK - I was thinking exactly the same thing, the hash table having an ID column as an anonymous, unsigned integer. I didn't bring that up, because you (obviously) can't change the PRIMARY KEY of a table that is stewarded by "closed-source software".

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I'm trying to solve is that with this design, a hash can
>   only belong to one job - in reality a hash can occur in many jobs, and
>   I'd like to know each job in which a hash occurs.
>
> The way I'm thinking of doing this is to create a new table called
>   'Jobs', with fields 'job_id', 'job_name' and 'hash_value'.

As long as you can *also* get a) the foreign keys right and b) the cascades right for both "job_id" and "hash_value", that should be fine.

*Duplicate data* and *redundant data* are technical terms in relational modeling. *Technical term*  means they have meanings that you're not likely to find in a dictionary. They don't mean "the same values appear in multiple tables." That *should* be obvious, because if you replace the values with surrogate ID numbers, those ID numbers will then appear in multiple tables.

Those technical terms actually mean "identical values with identical meaning." (Relevant: [Hugh Darwen's article](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/The-Relational-Model.pdf) for definition and use of predicates.)

There might be good, practical reasons for replacing text with an ID number, but there are no theoretical reasons to do that, and normalization certainly doesn't require it.  (There's no "every row has an ID number" normal form.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I'd vote it up if I had the rep :-)

Comment: Come back when you do. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If i read your question correctly, your design is fundamentally flawed, because of these two facts:

- the hash is the primary key (quoted from your question)
- the same hash can be generated from multiple different inputs (fact)
- you have millions of hashes (from question)

With the many millions of rows/hashes, eventually you'll get a hash collision.

The only sane approach is to have job_id as the primary key and hash in a column with a non-unique index on it. Finding job(s) given a hash would be straightforward.

Comment: According to the OP requirements, the `hash_value` is defined as the PRIMARY KEY by a "closed-source software" system that is beyond the control of the OP. So, in this case, adding a child `job` table is the appropriate approach.

Comment: @Bohemian - The system was designed around hash values, not jobs - the job was never really relevant in the early days.